# Where did I go wrong on trying to solve this question on an exam?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I took an exam yesterday, and I almost for a fact know I got this question wrong. I couldn't figure it out, since my answer wasn't an answer choice, so I ended up guessing. An explanation of what I did wrong and how to properly solve this would be great appreciated!
The question: 
Evaluate $f'(\frac{\pi}{6})$, where $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(\sin 2x)$. So these are the steps that I did. First using chain rule$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(\sin 2x)=\frac{1}{1+(\sin 2x)^2}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\sin(2x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(2x)=\cos(2x)\cdot2$$so $$\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(\sin 2x)=\frac{1}{1+(\sin 2x)^2}*2\cos(2x)$$
Plugging in $(\frac{\pi}{6})$ I ended with $$$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{1+(\sin\frac{\pi}{3})^2}\cdot2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$I ended with some answer that didn't match up with any of the answer choices, did I go about solving this wrong? If so, how would I solve it correctly?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: They probably expect you to know that $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$, and that (therefore) $\sin(\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}/2$. The calculation of the derivative, as far as you went, is fine.

Comment: And that $\sin(\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}/2$

Comment: I didn't.. :( My trig is horrible and I couldn't use a calculator. That was probably it. So otherwise, what I have is correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct way of solving it, would've gotten $4/7$ if you plugged those values in. Also, there's a bunch of useful tricks to help memorize the values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ for common values.

Comment: Ahhh, okay.I'm going to take some time to learn more trig, now that you all have mentioned that my mistakes are obvious. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Calculators are of great help for not finding out what's going on.

Comment: @Kenshin Look at (16) in this page http://oakroadsystems.com/twt/special.htm It is an easy way to remember sine and cosine of some special angles.

Comment: Haha, I'm going to take this as a wake up call and learn my trig values. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @mfl thank you! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Kenshin, look here for one of the more useful tricks (same technique as mfl but more organized) http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~loftin/precalcfal05/values.pdf

Comment: Appreciate the links, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the chain rule, and get $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1 + (\sin (2x))^2} \cdot \cos (2x) \cdot 2 $$

See the chain rule in action: the derivative of $\tan^{-1} x $ is $\frac{1}{1 + x^2}$. The derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$ and the derivative of $2x$ is $2$. Look at how everything fits.

Now: $$f' \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{3}} \cdot \cos \frac{\pi}{3} \cdot 2 = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{3}{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 = \frac{4}{7} $$